# git-svn How can I merge changes from a local git repo to a different remote svn branch?

Tags: git, svn, merge

I created a local git repository from an svn branch in order to use git's features and dcommit when all the work is ready. I had a very large change and it was postponed. The branch I was working on in svn has been merged to the trunk and removed.  A new release branch was created. If I were in svn, I would switch to the new branch and pull. Instead, I cloned the new branch and I want to merge my changes into it, then commit them. However, git apparently can't see their shared history and all my changes look like a conflict:

```
$ git svn clone --revision HEAD  https://svnedge.yadayada.com/svn/ASSIST/branches/FY15Q4X_AugMaint FY15Q4X_AugMaint
...edit,build,test....
$ git svn clone --revision HEAD  https://svnedge.yadayada.com/svn/ASSIST/branches/FY16Q1X_OctMaint FY16Q1X_OctMaint
$ git branch maint
$ git remote add hankr ../FY15Q4X_AugMaint
$ git checkout -t hankr/maint
$ git merge maint
... almost every file a conflict...
```

It was suggested that if I pulled in the entire repository, git would be able to see the shared history. I don't have any commit history to preserve, I just want my changes brought into the new release. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112073/git-svn-how-to-copy-git-commits-from-one-svn-branch-to-another -- contains some ideas, but it seems like it's doing more .

Answer (score 0):

I was merging in the wrong direction. Adding the remote "hank" and my prior work "../FY15Q4X_AugMaint" as a remote is correct.  You can pick up where you left off, that is, you can replay changes to SVN that you preserved in a local git-svn repo, by rebasing them onto the new SVN branch.

```
$ git remote add or ../ASSIST
$ git checkout -t hankr/maint
```

Your config should look like this:

```
# .git/config (were these created from command line or added?
[remote "hankr"]
    url = ../ASSIST
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/hankr/*
[branch "maint"]
    remote = hankr
    merge = refs/heads/maint
```

Now you should be able to rebase:

```
$ git rebase -i master
$ git merge maint
```

Of course, SVN lets you switch branches, so I could have done that, pulled the changes and resolve any conflicts on files.